# Gram-Schmidt coefficients in LLL algorithm

Tags: lattice-crypto, lenstra-lenstra-lovasz

To my understanding the LLL lattice reduction algorithm starts with a set of integer vectors $\{b_1, \dots, b_2\}$, which span a lattice, and tries to generate a new basis of shorter vectors of the same lattice.
It first defines the Gram-Schmidt orthogonal basis $\{b_1^\ast, \dots, b_2^\ast\}$ (which is in general not integer) and proceeds to find new vectors according to
$$
b_i \leftarrow b_i - \lfloor \mu_{i,j} \rceil b_j \,
$$
where the Gram-Schmidt coefficients  $\mu_{i,j}$ are given by
$$
\mu_{i,j} = \frac{(b_i, b^\ast_j)}{(b^\ast_j, b^\ast_j)} \,.
$$
This process is repeated iteratively (including some resorting of the $b_i$) until certain criteria are met.

However, naively I could also imagine to use
$$
\tilde \mu_{i,j} = \frac{(b_i, b_j)}{(b_j, b_j)}
$$
instead of $\mu_{i,j}$ in the above replacement rule.
In particular, if one tries to minimize the norm of $b_i + \lambda b_j$ analytically by taking the derivative of
$$
\|b_i + \lambda b_j\|^2 = \|b_i\|^2 + 2 \lambda (b_i, b_j) + \lambda^2 \|b_j\|^2
$$
with respect to $\lambda$ and setting the resulting expression to zero, the optimal $\lambda$ is exactly given by $- \tilde \mu_{i,j}$ (and not $- \mu_{i,j}$).
So I would imagine that the shortest possible vector on the lattice is obtained by rounding this value to the closest integer.

Therefore, my question is: Why does LLL use the coefficients $\mu_{i,j}$ and not $\tilde \mu_{i,j}$? For just two input vectors they are literally the same, but do they guarantee a shorter runtime or better results (despite my naive argument) in the higher dimensional case?